# Прямая или косвенно-прямая речь?

Tags: прямая-речь, пунктуация

Сказать "Следуй за мной" может далеко не каждый.

Нужно ли двоеточие перед "Следуй за мной"? Если нужно, то будет ли уместным после кавычек тире? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сказать "следуй за мной" может далеко не каждый. Здесь нераспространенная прямая речь выступает в качестве дополнения - сказать (что?).

Пояснение.

а) Нераспространенная   прямая речь может являться членом предложения – подлежащим, дополнением, несогласованным определением.

б) В этом случае прямая речь не имеет собственной интонации и вписывается интонационную модель всего предложения.

в)  Прямая речь заключается в кавычки, но двоеточие перед ней не ставится.

г)  Допускается использование как прописной, так и строчной буквы в начале прямой реи.

д)  При значительной  распространенности  высказывания применяется обычное оформление прямой речи.

Answer (score 1):

Да, я бы так и оформила: Сказать: "Следуй за мной"- может далеко не каждый.

Answer (score 1):

У Розенталя есть такое:

Примечание. Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но перед ними двоеточие не ставится, например: Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Гоголь); Предположение дневального, что «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе», все больше собирало сторонников (Фадеев); Он вспомнил пословицу «Не плюй в колодец...» и отошел в сторону; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.

Судя по этому замечанию, надо написать так:

Сказать "следуй за мной" может далеко не каждый.