# Надо ли здесь оформлять прямую речь?

Tags: прямая-речь

Все сертификационные центры, к которым обращался автор, ответили «да», и на него надо декларацию и сертификат соответствия по ТР ТС 032/2013 на изготовление и применение.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант с упрощенным оформлением прямой речи (прямая речь в роли дополнения)**:

*Все сертификационные центры, к которым обращался автор, ответили «Да, и на него надо декларацию и сертификат соответствия по ТР ТС 032/2013 на изготовление и применение».*

Нераспространенная   прямая речь может являться членом предложения – подлежащим, дополнением, несогласованным определением. Прямая речь заключается в кавычки, но двоеточие перед ней не ставится. Допускается использование как прописной, так и строчной буквы в начале прямой речи.

При значительной  распространенности  высказывания применяется **обычное оформление прямой речи.**

Пример: *Я только посмотрел на неё, а она отвернулась и, сказавши «ступайте за мной, мой паж», пошла к флигелю.*

Comment: Сергей, а почему у вас вся последующая часть после слова "да"в кавычках? Разве прямая речь здесь не слово "да"?

Comment: Да, здесь можно подумать, что продолжение предложения - это продолжение прямой речи, но если сохранять волю автора, то предложение требует изменения, напр. разбить на два: "Следовательно, на него надо декларацию..."

Comment: Меня же интересовало, можно ли оставить "да" в кавычках, не оформляя как прямую речь.

Comment: Мне кажется, что тогда союз И не справляется со  своей задачей, его лучше заменить, например: Все сертификационные центры, к которым обращался автор, ответили «да, то есть на него надо декларацию и сертификат соответствия по ТР ТС 032/2013 на изготовление и применение».

Comment: Исходя из того, как Вы оформили цитату в данном случае, я делаю вывод, что и "да" в кавычках оставить тоже можно.

Comment: Ну да, конечно, тогда это короткая прямая речь в роли дополнения. Но если оставить союз И, то кажется, что вторая  часть предложения  входит  прямую речь (по крайней мере, мне так показалось). Поэтому замена союза сделана для того, чтобы разделить их.

Comment: Но и после замены у вас почему-то прямая речь осталось в качестве целого предложения.Для чего тогда замена?

Comment: Извините, небольшая неточность (скопировано, но не исправлено), исправляю :"Мне кажется, что тогда союз И не справляется со своей задачей, его лучше заменить, например: Все сертификационные центры, к которым обращался автор, ответили «да", то есть на него надо декларацию и сертификат соответствия по ТР ТС 032/2013 на изготовление и применение.

Comment: Да, этот вариант лучше. Двусмысленность пропадает.

Answer (score 1):

Ааа! На кого "на него"?! На автора?! Не указан объект обсуждения.

Можно попробовать так:

> Все сертификационные центры, к которым обращался автор, ответили «да»,
>   и на **(изобретение / изделие / продукт / товар / оборудование)** надо
>   **(оформить)** декларацию и сертификат соответствия по ТР ТС 032/2013 на изготовление и применение.
>
> ---

По поводу *да-и-нет-не-говорить-чёрный-белый-не-носить* - привет от Справки Грамоты.ру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Здесь можно оформить как косвенно-прямую речь (подробнее - [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/28257)), но тогда закавычить надо весь фрагмент:

***Все сертификационные центры, к которым обращался автор, ответили «Да, и на него надо декларацию и сертификат соответствия по ТР ТС 032/2013 на изготовление и применение».***

Это, думаю, самая естественная пунктуация из возможных. 
"Да" в этом случае в отдельных кавычках не нуждается.

Можно, думается, и без кавычек (как у вас), но это опасный вариант, он подразумевает косвенную речь с опущенным союзом "что". В разговорной речи оно дело обычное, но на письме не все поймут такую конструкцию. К тому же возникает вопрос, а надо ли в этом случае оставлять в кавычках это "да": опять же вопрос, считать ли отдельную частицу кусочком косвенно-прямой речи... Короче, я бы не рисковал, забрал бы все в кавычки - и не мучился.

*Другие ответы крайне сомнительны, не хочу даже комментировать.
Galina вообще о чем-то своем, a Sergey дал такую же рекомендацию, но съехал на какое-то немыслимое объяснение*.